# ¿Como mostrar en pantalla registros de BBDD en Python?

Tags: python

Hola que tal espero que bien. Cuando ejecuto en Python la parte del menú se ejecuta bien pero cuando tendría que mostrar los datos de la persona que se encuentra en la tabla me aparece [].

```
Selecciona una opción para Buscar Paciente
    1 - Por DNI
    2 - Por nombre
    3 - Por edad
    9 - salir
inserta un numero valor >> 1
Ingrese DNI: 40396902
[]


        ^
```

Desde ***Pacientes BBDD.py*** llamo a esta funcion que se encuentra en ***Pacientes_f.py***

```
Lista_Paciente(miPuntero)
```

Funciones de ***Pacientes_f.py***

```
def menuListap():
    import os
    os.system('cls')
    print ("Selecciona una opción para Buscar Paciente")
    print ("\t1 - Por DNI")
    print ("\t2 - Por nombre")
    print ("\t3 - Por edad")
    print ("\t9 - salir")




def Lista_Paciente(p):
    while True:

        menuListap()
        opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")


        if opcionMenu=="1":
            #POR DNI
            dni = int(input("Ingrese DNI: "))
            p.execute("SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI='dni'")
            paciente = p.fetchall()
            print(paciente)

        elif opcionMenu=="2":
            #POR NOMBRE
            nombre = str(input("Ingrese nombre: "))
            p.execute("SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE NOMBRE_PACIENTE= '?'", nombre)
            paciente = p.fetchall()
            print(paciente)

        elif opcionMenu=="3":
            #POR EDAD
            edad = int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
            p.execute("SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE EDAD= '?'", edad)
            paciente = p.fetchall()
            print(paciente)

        elif opcionMenu=="9":
            break

        else:
            print ("")
            input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

A mi criterio el error se encuentra en el momento que intento introducir la variable tanto dni, nombre como edad al código sql.

PD: si en la parte de `p.execute("SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI='dni'")` en vez de poner la variable dni introduzco el numero de dni (`p.execute("SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI='40396902'")`) en si me lo ejecuta perfectamente pero la idea es que sea introducida por teclado y no manualmente.

Comment: te sugiero armar la sentencia previamente algo asi: sql = " SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI= " + str(dni)....luego va  p.execute(sql)...

Comment: tambien verifica que obtengas el dni con un print dni..de igual manera verifica tu sentencia si esta bien armada con print sql

Comment: Ya verifique lo del dni lo obtengo perfectamente, en cuanto a la sentencia no entiendi como hacerla previamente. @Tegito123

Comment: ya agregue mi respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Tegito123 ahora intentare ver si me funciona!

Comment: para python 3 puedes hacer algo como : `sql = 'SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI={}'.format(dni)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero armar tu sentencia sql previamente:

```
dni = int(input("Ingrese DNI: "))
sql = "SELECT * FROM MI_TABLA WHERE dni = '"+str(dni)+"'"
print (sql)
```

pedimos el dni, a continuacion formamos la sentencia sql como se mostro arriba, el posible resultado seria algo asi:

[image: result]

Finalmente solo deberias poner algo como esto:

```
dni = int(input("Ingrese DNI: "))
sql = "SELECT * FROM MI_TABLA WHERE dni = '"+str(dni)+"'"
p.execute(sql)
#ponemos sql porque es alli donde tiene mi sentencia a ejecutar
```

Espero te sirva y te ayude

**Actualización**
Intenta con la siguiente sentencia:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM mi_tabla WHERE dni = '%s' """ % (dni)
```

Comment: Mmmm no me funciono, salio en pantalla el "SELECT * FROM PACIENTES WHERE DNI = '"+str(dni)+"'"

Comment: ese es el error que te genera ?

Comment: @GerónimoMembiela ya actualize mi respuesta..checala

Comment: SOLUCIONADO ! gracias por el codigo Tegito ! @Tegito123